# How can I calculate if my data is diverse

Tags: statistics, sampling

I conducted a survey in which the first question I asked students what year they were in. I want to check that I have a diverse amount of students (from many year groups) so I can say the survey data represents the population of all students.

the results look like this:
[graph results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAL7h.png)
the data looks like this :

```
year 1: 2 people 
year 2: 10 people 
year 3: 8 people 
year 4: 5 people
year 5+: 0 people
```

There were 25 respondents in total and there were 5 options (of year groups) for them to choose from.

From my data is it fair to say I have a varied range of respondents across year groups? Is it fair to say the rest of the data reflects all students across year groups?

Comment: Well, it sure doesn't look fair.  Are there actually no students in years $5+$ in the population?  Is the ratio between year $2$ and year $1$ really $5:1$?  More broadly, what does "fair" mean to you in this context?

Comment: I just wondered if there was a statistical value which determined how representable my data is. I can tell by looking at the data it isnt very spread or "fair", but is there any calculation I can use?

Comment: "Fair" isn't really well defined.  As a general matter, statistics allows you to predict (probabilistically) whether a sample of a given size is likely to match some given statistic within some desired range.  But that doesn't tell you much about any particular sample.  Size alone doesn't do it.  If my sample consists of $100$ million women, then it is is extremely unfair as to gender balance but it might be perfectly fair as to, say, handedness (N.B.  I have no idea whether or not that is true).

Comment: Thank you for your insight lulu, I will rethink my approach

Comment: Statistics is a powerful tool, but it can be frustrating and it is easily misused.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning: I am not a statistician, so please consult one if you really need exact answers on this question. However, I think what follows isn't bad advice.

I think that if you really need to ensure that you have sampled "fairly" from each year for whatever your survey is about then you should probably go back and re-survey using some kind of [stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling) technique. Otherwise you are probably going to run into the trap of "forcing" your data to be "fair" by choosing some clever ad-hoc definition, which might actually *invalidate* your results.

If you can't afford to re-survey using an appropriate technique, the next best thing you could do is simply be honest about your sampling methodology and move forward by ensuring that you refer only to the entire student population, without regard to year. Don't try and draw any conclusions about individual years since you didn't set up the survey correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am taking a look at this stratified sampling now. I will avoid drawing conclusions based on year groups. I was just looking statistical value to reference as to why this data is diverse/not diverse